# Remove annoying WP Adminbar CSS

Tags: php, theme-development, core

I am trying to remove the annoying WP Admin bar css.

```
<style type="text/css" media="screen">
html { margin-top: 32px !important; }
* html body { margin-top: 32px !important; }
@media screen and ( max-width: 782px ) {
    html { margin-top: 46px !important; }
    * html body { margin-top: 46px !important; }
}
</style>
```

I have tried (according to other OLD answers):

```
/**
 * Remove admin bar CSS
 */

  function remove_admin_login_header() {
      remove_action('wp_head', '_admin_bar_bump_cb');
  }
  add_action('get_header', 'remove_admin_login_header');
```

It does not work.

Comment: Do you just want to remove the CSS, or the whole admin bar? If you only remove this CSS then the admin bar will overlap the top of the page.

Answer (score 1):

Good morning!

This filter should work `add_filter('show_admin_bar', '__return_false');` right from the [wordpress codex.](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/show_admin_bar)

Alternatively, you can disable it from specific users.[image]

Comment: He wants to remove just the CSS, not the admin bar itself.

Answer (score 1):

You can disable it for everybody :

```
add_filter('show_admin_bar', '__return_false');
```

or do conditionally hide it :

```
 add_filter('show_admin_bar', 'my_function_to_hide_it');
function my_function_to_hide_it(){
// condition and return true or false 
}
```

All details there : https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/show_admin_bar

Answer (score 1):

The correct way according to a comment in the WordPress source code [wp-includes/class-wp-admin-bar.php:60](https://github.com/WordPress/WordPress/blob/d7c0343d5f7e0efdad5b7dce64981e74f5d0b7a0/wp-includes/class-wp-admin-bar.php#L59-L62) is to remove the CSS callback via theme support.

This would look like:

```php
add_action('after_setup_theme', function () {
    add_theme_support('admin-bar', ['callback' => '__return_false']);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

This filter removes the CSS and hides the adminbar on the entire site:

```
function hide_admin_bar_from_front_end(){
    remove_action( 'wp_head', '_admin_bar_bump_cb' );
    return false;
}
add_filter( 'show_admin_bar', 'hide_admin_bar_from_front_end' );
```

If you want to disable the CSS only, you must return `true` instead of `false`.

If you need it conditionally:

```
function wpse_maybe_remove_adminbar() {
    if ( your_condition ) {
        add_filter( 'show_admin_bar', 'hide_admin_bar_from_front_end' );
    }
}
add_action('wp_head', 'wpse_maybe_remove_adminbar', 0);

function hide_admin_bar_from_front_end(){
    remove_action( 'wp_head', '_admin_bar_bump_cb' );
    return false;
}
```